# Answer File in Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I am trying to create a Setup Project in Visual Studio. I want it to be an unattended install. Any idea how I can pass in an answer file to it? So far, I am thinking I can create a custom Install action and copy the contents of the answer file (passed in as a parameter), to another file. Is this the right approach or are there other standard ways to process answer files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a normal setup you don't really need a answer file. Just [call your setup file with the q-switch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/227091) and everything should be installed with the default configuration.

```
msiexec -i c:\pathtofile\mypackage.msi /q
```

If your really have to change some default values, although you might just change them directly in the setup project, those can also be changed when calling the msi like this:

```
msiexec -i c:\pathtofile\mypackage.msi ALLUSERS=1
```

A complete list of the [Property Reference can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: We have a lot of values that need to be configured. Passing them as command line values can be cumbersome, which is why we need an answer file.